# Is there any risk to host image on googleusercontent?

Tags: web-hosting

I saw some websites hosting their images on Google. I guess it's free and can save a lot of cost.

Is there any risk to do so?

Comment: There's risks to doing anything. What kind of risks are you concerned about?

Comment: If it’s for free, why people buy traffic from hosting companies? Why not just upload everything to google? I’m wondering whether there is a limit or something

Comment: Do they have an FAQ that explains the limits? I can't seem to find anything that says this is even open to the public.

Comment: @JohnConde you can easily upload images to googleusercontent by inserting them into Google docs, then you can share the URL.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Is there any traffic limit?

Comment: You can also copy the googleusercontent URL directly from Google photos, regardless of whether the content is shared or not. However, maybe I'm missing a trick, but this seems like it could be a very time consuming way to manage more than a handful of images?

Comment: Since this hasn't been answered, I'm marking it as a duplicate of the newer question that was just asked rather than the other way around.