# Is it bad to hotlink images hosted on googleusercontent.com?

Tags: seo, hotlinking

When copy-pasting content from Google Docs into our CMS, images are hotlinked to `lh3.googleusercontent.com`.

Most images on that page (except the first one) are linked in this way.

Is there any problems with leaving them like this? It is quite time consuming to extract all the images and manually re-link them all. What advantages are there to hosting them on our own domain?

Comment: This was asked two years ago but never answered [Is there any risk to host image on googleusercontent?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129816/is-there-any-risk-to-host-image-on-googleusercontent) I've marked the other question a duplicate of this one and hopefully somebody can answer this time.

Answer (score 2):

Hosting on your own domain increases the calls to your own hosting, so there are benefits to hosting elsewhere. It's quite common to host images at an external source (ie. CDN).

You are allowed to hotlink to images on your Google Docs. However, you have to have the rights to use that image. There are also some browser plugins which block that server, so keep that in mind as well. You are also at the mercy of Google and their constant changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a photo on your CMS, then firstly it will be faster to load content, and secondly so you can get to Google photos, which can attract ranked traffic, in third if the photos disappear, then you have to restore them in the articles on your site, well, and just basic you will not have extra links anywhere else, but only your internal photo
Of course, as one respondent has already said, if you do not want to store images on your site, then use CDN as an option